# Insert entity in NestJS / TypeOrm / Postgres

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, liquibase

Here is my entity :

```js
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Client } from './client.entity';

@Entity({ name: 'directory_dir' })
export class Directory extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid", { name: 'dir_id' })
  id: string;

  @Column( { name: 'dir_name' } )
  name: string;

  @JoinColumn({ name: 'cli_client_id'})
  @ManyToOne(() => Client, { eager: true })
  client: Client;

}
```

The table is created via liquibase :

```xml
  <changeSet id="3" author="Me">
    <createTable tableName="DIRECTORY_DIR">
      <column name="DIR_ID" type="uuid">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
      </column>
      <column name="DIR_NAME" type="varchar(64)">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
      </column>
      <column name="CLI_CLIENT_ID" type="uuid">
        <constraints nullable="false" foreignKeyName="FK_DIRECTORY_DIR_CLI_CLIENT_ID" references="CLIENT_CLI(CLI_ID)"/>
      </column>
    </createTable>
  </changeSet>
```

I struggle to have it inserted into the database. I have tried several syntaxes but every time, I get an error because the id is not auto-generated:

> null value in column "dir_id" of relation "directory_dir" violates not-null constraint

I tried this :

```js
    const directory = new Directory();
    /* Also tried this one
     * const directory = this.directoryRepository.create({
     * name: makeDirRequest.name,
     * client: user.client
     * });
    */
    directory.name = makeDirRequest.name;
    directory.client = user.client;
    this.logger.log('directory', JSON.stringify(directory));
    // Also tried with insert instead of save
    return await this.directoryRepository.save(directory);
```

In the logs, I can see that there is no `dir_id` but, in the way I understand it, it should not be a problem, as I expect TypeOrm to do it when generating the `INSERT` statement.

When I insert entities in the database with SQL statements, I can easily find them from typeORM so the typeORM configuration seems ok.

Comment: Do you have any migration script? or is it for the first time that table created?

Comment: The table was just created from liquibase and was empty

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from the definition of the table in PostgreSQL. A default value must be supplied in order to explain how to auto-generate the primary key.

Declaring the column like this in Liquibase does the job :

```xml
<column name="DIR_ID" type="uuid" defaultValue="gen_random_uuid()">
  <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
</column>
```

I just added `defaultValue="gen_random_uuid()"`.

`gen_random_uuid()` is the new `uuid_generate_v4()`, available from Postgres 13

From this point, I could just create the entity and insert it like this :

```js
return await Directory.create({
  name: makeDirRequest.name,
  client: user.client
}).save();
```